# How to prevent dbContext.Database.Migrate from running for EntityFramework Core CLI execution?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

It seems that my application runs through at least the Configure phase of application startup when running commands like `dotnet ef migrations add ...`.  The result is that the migrations are being applied to the database, even when I run the command `dotnet ef migrations script`.

Is there a way to "detect" if a dotnet ef cli command is being run so that I can prevent the command `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` from running?

`.Migrate()` is currently being called from the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class, with the dbContext having been injected as a parameter of the `Configure()` method.

ex.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                      IHostingEnvironment env,
                      MyDbContext myDbContext)
{
   myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#move-database-initialization-code